# When editing an object in 2.93, how do you stop the other objects from becoming translucent

Tags: edit-mode

Very often I need to edit the mesh of an object which lies on top of another object. The definition of the underlying object turns translucent or shaded. Is there any way to stop this. Previous versions of blender did not do this. The lower image is what it should be.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: The menu] Are you asking about this "Fade Inactive Geometry" setting in the Overlays menu?